# Couldn't get connection factory client in logcat

Tags: java, android, gps, maps

I'm using an **HTC Explorer** to test my app

Everything was fine , till I altered the code to show my current location. The app works , but the following error is logged in on Logcat : **Couldn't get connection factory client**

Here is my code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.com.draft1;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;




public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {




private LocationManager lm;
public LocationListener locationListener;

 // locationListener location =new MyLocationListener();

MapView mapView;
MapController mc;

GeoPoint p;



String coordinates[] = {"41.146064", "-80.642861"};
double lat=Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
double lng=Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener =new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    p=new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(lng*1E6));
    mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);


    mc=mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(p);

    //mc.setZoom(13);
    //mapView.invalidate();


    //myMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(lng*1E6)));
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {




    p=new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(loc.getLongitude()*1E6));

    if(loc!= null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location : lat"+loc.getLatitude()+" Long "+loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    mc.animateTo(p);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,int status,Bundle extras) {

    }
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 

{
    //adssad

    return false;

}



}
```

Why exactly is this happening ?

Any Possible solutions ?

I'd really appreciate some help with this

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random Error by Google it seems.Started working on its own :|