# Android MapView:Couldn't find the connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, mapactivity

As I know, that question is discussed so many time here, but still as I tried I faced the same issue and did all try what I saw here and also by Google but still that issue is unresolved.

Also, I tried the sample codes from so many sites and there also the same problem.(Issue that on `MapActivity` derived class, I can see the `grid` but map not loading while threw aforesaid exception)

I tried with my own `API key` as well as the keys already present in the sample code. And, also tried in device with keeping Location option enable and disable both.

Please do provide me your assistance.

Below is used one manifest file...

**

```
<permission
      android:name="com.Example.appl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.Example.appl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.Example.appl.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MHomeActivity"></activity>





</application>
```

**

Comment: have you got any issues?

Comment: Hey Sivaraj, Please check the subject line for the exception as I faced and also in Log I found some server err 3...

Comment: have you used this permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />?

Comment: Yeah Sivaraj, I did and has also added COARSE.FINE and other also. Not only this also tried by adding the permissions like READ/WRITE, GPRS, etc... but still having the issue...

Comment: can you post your log and manifest here?

Comment: Sure, I do.. just a minute...

Comment: Hey Please check the same below my raised query...

Comment: where did you use internet permission?

Comment: just a sec, may be here full content is not seeing.. Let me post that part in comment...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Mezzotint.docadvice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: that's between uses-sdk and application tag, as you can see above...

Comment: And, actually I don't get how could I do copy from LogCat so to provide you the exception too..

Comment: what is your google api version?

Comment: It's Google api[Android 4.0]

Comment: will you use this permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> and check the android:minSdkVersion="7" once

Comment: I've also tested with these tags.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>..Please check...

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after messing two days, I got the solution still if someone has best please update me.

What I did, after reviewing so many threads and links, I got to know that nothing is wrong with above code/manifest, so I dig into the Google Map API key and below solution see me the way...(Please note that I'm doing my development over mac).

First of all I open my terminal and at there I accessed at Java folder and within it bin folder, then type following beneath command :-

```
***keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore \User\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android***
```

Please note that in above command "\User.android\debug.keystore" This is the path where your android debug key is kept, in case in eclipse if you want to find that path(may be it's different on your system), use following:

```
**eclipse->window->preferences->Android->Build**
```

So, when you run above command, you'll find the MD5 key and then you need to access following link:-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup

Here, at beneath you'll give above obtained MD5 key and it'll generate api key for you for debug.
That's all then supply this api key either at required xml or coding(Depends how you code).

But this provision is for v1. If someone found a way for v2, please update this thread.

Comment: this is the first real solution I've founded.

Comment: Thanks, rkmax for your feedback.

Comment: Have you found a solution to Maps API v2 API for use with Android 10?

Comment: Hi rkmax, actually I didn't allot my task further for v2 as need to deliver the project, but I need to do so will update you and in case if you find something please update this post.

Comment: i've founded solution read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745850/android-mapviewcouldnt-find-the-connection-factory-client/14994638#14994638). It works fine on a Galaxy ACE

Answer (score 0):

Check wether you have added the map library in android-manifest file inside Application tag.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Pardoning to see you late... Dude, I've already kept this tag in my manifest within the application tag... Please suggest me things which you think might be the reason of that issue...

Answer (score 0):

I searched your problem I have the solution and given below please refer these...

[Couldn't get connection factory client in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555174/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-in-logcat)

[Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

Comment: That's not the solution as that's not the problem related to clear and run the code again...This is a serious issue which I'm facing from yesterday morning and still continue...

Comment: have got maps.jar file in your library

Comment: from where should I get this jar?

Comment: I checked that jar is already present in the Google api folder in the structure...

Answer (score 0):

After read and browse a lot the answer for use the API v2 even if you are develop for Android 2.2

#### Get the signature SHA1

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

get something like  (SHA1): 82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3

#### Get API_KEY

Go to [Google Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) in Services set ON to `Google Maps Api v2` later in Api Access section click on Create new Android Key or Update if you has one, put inside dialog

```
82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3:82:73:C3;COM.PACKAGE.NAME
```

#### Add libraries

Add the `google-play-services` to your project, Go to `Project properties -> Android` in the section "Library" click Add and browse to `sdk-android>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`.

Check for `android-support-v4.jar` library in your Project dependencies.

#### Edit your code

```
<!--AndroidManifest.xml-->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<permission android:name="COM.PACKAGE.NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="COM.PACKAGE.NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!--inside <application> tag-->
<meta-data android:value="API_KEY" android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"/>
```

in your Activity class your need extend from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

```
//MainActivity.java

package COM.PACKAGE.NAME;    

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and for last you need change your `activity_main.xml`

```
<!--./res/layout/activity_main.xml-->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response but that also I had tried and tested in simulator as well as in my own Carbon(A1+ series) and Samsung mobile, I did faced the same issue.. but let me go once again and will update you

Comment: Today i've tested it in my Galaxy SIII with Android 4.1.1 and works well!