# Android Maps V2 App constantly crashes

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a problem with my app that uses the android api v2 in that it won't start it only keeps saying that "Unfortunately, app_name has stopped working.", I have followed every step in the guide released by google and I have also looked up similar problems here in StackOverflow and tried there solution but none seems to work unfortunately.

One of the biggest problem I seem to have is this

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

even though I have added the Google Play services library and have added it to the app project. so where does the problem lie?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SupportMapFragment mMap;
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            googleMap = mMap.getMap();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: can you post your layout file too ?

Comment: Can you post what device / emulator settings you are using?

Comment: Here is the device/emulator settings http://i47.tinypic.com/15qwvgx.jpg, 
and here is the layout xml:


**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>**

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745850/android-mapviewcouldnt-find-the-connection-factory-client/14994638#14994638)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing your application on Emulator or device..Because the google MapV2 requires a Android device with Google play apk installed in it.

Comment: Yes, I am running it on an emulator and why doesn't it work on emulators, where does it say that it only works on android smartphones?

Comment: Please check the official link to clarify your doubt which says:

Note: Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet.


http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

EDIT ---
I recommend you try the [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) instead of the eclipse android emulator.

### But you can try the steps below.

You can do this steps if you alred have your API KEY

**Step 1:**

configuration AndroindManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.br.activitys"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.br.activitys.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.br.activitys.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
         android:debuggable="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY" />

        <activity> ... </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Step 2:**
Create an emulator 4.2.2 API 17

[image]

After that, start and wait this completely loaded.
 
Step 3:
Download the files https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8p5jsvg9i4l5j3/com.android.vending-20130716.apk e https://www.dropbox.com/s/a90mjl9nhk4qv45/com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk
Install it with ADB
On windows exceute type CMD

[image]

The prompt will opne and you need to access your android instalation folder, in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

[image]

So, you will type ADB INSTALL and the path of the files you downloaded.
 [image]

and

[image]

This process take some time(2 or 3 minutes), dont worry.

After that,you need restart the emulator.

**step 4:**
Download https://www.dropbox.com/s/42bz5imaq4uty4j/google_play_services_9.7z extract the folder google_play_services insde of folder extra/google non your SDK directory (in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google), if the folder alredy exist, delete and replace with this new one.
Now, copy the same folder google-play-services_lib which is in google_play_services\libproject to your workspace, and import like an eclipse project.
File -> Import

[image]

Select Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace

[image]

Select the folder you copied

[image]

and Finish.

**Step 5:** 
Now add the library to your project.
Right Click in your project and go to properties.
In android, scroll down until library and click add.

[image]

Choose the project you imported, and click ok

[image]

[image]

Just for sure, go Project -> Clean and select Clean All Projects

[image]

It's done, now just run your app.

[image]