# Add google map in activity by viewPager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to show map in activity by using viewPager but I am still getting rendering problem in xml file.

> A fragment tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different 
>   layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be 
>   used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like 
>   previewed while editing the layout.
>    -
>
> (Pick Layout...)
>
> Do not warn about  tags in this session

add_masjid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/xyz"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rect1"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:text="@string/abc"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/generalId"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@+id/editText1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generalId" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is also creating an error in Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.saroosh.masjidnow, PID: 9220
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs.AddMasjid.onCreateView(AddMasjid.java:26)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
```

AddMasjid.java

```
package com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class AddMasjid extends Fragment {

    MapView gMapView;
    GoogleMap gMap = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_masjid,container,false);

//        gMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
//        gMapView.getMapAsync(this);
//        gMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        gMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
//        try {
//            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        return v;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
//        gMap = map;
//        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
//                LatLng(49.39,-124.83), 20));
//    }
//    @Override
//    public void onResume() {
//        super.onResume();
//        gMapView.onResume();
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onPause() {
//        super.onPause();
//        gMapView.onPause();
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onDestroy() {
//        super.onDestroy();
//        gMapView.onDestroy();
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onLowMemory() {
//        super.onLowMemory();
//        gMapView.onLowMemory();
//    }


}
```

Please tell me how can I fix this problem.

Comment: This is due to the fact that the preview doesn't know what will be in the fragment, as mentioned here [google-map-v2-fragment-rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898992/android-studio-google-map-v2-fragment-rendering) you can ignore this error.

Comment: But it is still creating an error in Logcat.

Comment: @KLajdPaja It's not satisfactory answer in my case.

Comment: @Nabia Saroosh without mapFragment you coding runing??

Comment: It's must show this fragment in my app but it is still crashing due to this error which is in Logcat.

Comment: At the end of your logcat must be the true error why inflation isn't being done like for e.g API key missing,  [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20468491/4091231)

Answer (score 0):

Use *com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment* instead of *com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView*

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generalId" />
```

Comment: I have to use this code but still I am facing this problem, thanks for your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding below code in xml instead of fragment.

add_masjid.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/generalId">

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

instead of

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generalId" />
```

or this code in java also.

```
package com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class AddMasjid extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    MapView gMapView;
    GoogleMap gMap = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_masjid,container,false);

        gMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        gMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        gMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(0,0), 0));
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        gMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        gMapView.onLowMemory();
    }


}
```